# Producer consumer multiple mutex needed to access critical section?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

There are 3 tools. A consumer needs 2 tools to modify the buffer. If consumer A takes the 2 tools and consumer B takes 1, consumer B will have to wait for another tool to be released.

I am not sure if I'm thinking about this problem in the right way. The way I interpret it is that I need 3 mutex and the consumer has to lock 2 out 3, is this the right idea?

I don't think I should be using semaphores because I don't want multiple threads accessing a shared resource at the same time. In a normal producer consumer problem there is just 1 mutex lock but here I need any 2 of the 3 how do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use 3 mutexes, but you must be careful to avoid deadlock. To do so, you must establish a well known order to acquire locks: for example, always acquire the lock for the tool with the lowest identifier first. In situations like these, avoiding deadlock is always a matter of acquiring locks in the same order.

Some pseudo-code:

```
pthread_mutex_t locks[3]; // 1 lock for each tool

critical_function() {
    /* Acquire 2 tools, t1 and t2 */
    first = min(t1, t2);
    second = max(t1, t2);
    locks[first].lock();
    locks[second].lock();
    /* Do work... */
    locks[first].unlock();
    locks[second].unlock();
}
```

This assumes that you associate an ID to each tool in the range `0-2`.

But notice, if you will, that no more than one producer / consumer can be working at the same time, since there are 3 tools only. So you might want to use a single mutex instead, lock it, acquire 2 tools, do the work and release it - after all, there is not much possibility for parallelism, you will have at most one producer / consumer working, and the others waiting while holding 1 tool.

Comment: You're right there's no parallelism. In my scenario I have 1 producer and 3 consumers. Let's say there's tool0,tool1,tool2. I want to make it possible for consumerA to accquire any 2 of those so Consumer A can be using tool 1 and 2. Consumer B obtains tool 0 and is waiting for another tool to be released and consumer C has none. When Consumer A releases tool1 and 2, Consumer B should be able to grab any tool, tool 1 or tool2 or maybe Consumer C grabs both before B grabs a tool. I am not sure how to approach this as there is no order.

Comment: @user3400882 Well, my answer is supposed to help - is there a specific part you didn't understand? The method I showed should be fit for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all see what are your shared resources? **Tools** of course. Now there are three tools and two of them are required to do work. So we need to be careful whenever a consumer wants to acquire tools. Suppose the function `AcquireTools()` assigns the tools to a consumer. Now this can easily be solved.
First we declare a global variable `mutex` and initialize it to 1. Then,

```
wait(mutex);   
AcquireTools();
//do work
signal(mutex);
```

suppose consumerA wants the two tools, it will call `wait(mutex)` and the value of `mutex` changes to `0`. Now while consumerA is working, consumerB wants the two tools. It will call `wait(mutex)`, but the value of `mutex=0`, so it can't go ahead until consumerA signals and the value of `mutex` changes back to `1`.